# Save Image from URL to Amazon S3 using PHP

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3

I'm looking for some help and direction on how I can pull an image from a URL (these are my own images) and move/upload the image to my Amazon S3 bucket, using PHP.

For example, let's say the image I need is:

http://myhost.com/image.jpg

I would like to be able to move this image (image.jpg) to my S3 server.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework has an [Amazon S3](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html) component which can make it easier for you to connect to your S3 programmatically. You don't need to use or install the whole Zend Framework. This component works also just like that.